# C# set focus on textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, focus, controls

I'm trying to set the "txtMiles" textbox to focus after:

1. The form opens
2. When the "clear" button is clicked

I have tried using `txtMiles.Focus();` but it doesn't seem to work for me.

***CODE BEING USED ON THIS FORM***

```
        private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //assigns variable in memory.
            double txtMile = 0;
            double Results;

            try
            {
                // here is where the math happens.
                txtMile = double.Parse(txtMiles.Text);
                Results = txtMile * CONVERSION;
                lblResults.Text = Results.ToString("n2");
                txtMiles.Focus();
            }
                // if the user enters an incorrect value this test will alert them of such.
            catch
            {
                //MessageBox.Show (ex.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("You entered an incorrect value");
                txtMiles.Focus();
            }
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //This empties all the fields on the form.
            txtMiles.Text = "";
            txtMiles.Focus();
            lblResults.Text = "";
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // closes program
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: no need to set  txtMiles.Focus(); programatically just in properties set  Tabindex  1 it will give required output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this solution worked perfectly...

txtMiles.Select();

Answer (score 10):

You should make sure your TabIndex is set and then instead of `Focus()`, try use `Select()`. See this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wt11hea.aspx).

```
txtMiles.Select();
```

Also make sure there isn't a `TabStop = true` attribute set in the view file.

Answer (score 4):

It's old, but someone could need this.

`Control.Focus()` is bugged. If it's not working, try workaround:

```
this.SelectNextControl(_controlname, true, true, true, true);
```

Change function parameters so they will work with your control, and remember about TabStop = true property of your control.

Answer (score 2):

You already have your txtMiles focused after the clear-button click. As for the Startup, set txtMiles.Focus() in your load-method.

```
private void MilesToKilometers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtMiles.Focus();
}
```